# "X and Y is" or "X and Y are"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, be, compound-subjects

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> Secondly, doing research and inventing new things are only possible if someone has understood the concepts in that particular topic or area.

I'm concerned about the use of the verb ***to be**.* 
Grammarly claims that I should use "is" instead of "are". 
I am under the impression that I am listing two activities –
doing research and inventing – and hence, I should use "are". 
Is it not similar to saying "X and Y are not feasible"
or "X and Y are bad boys"?

Comment: Grammarly is a computer program that only understands grammar to a very limited extent; while it is useful in that it identifies a lot of grammatical errors, some of its comments are completely wrong and should be ignored.

Comment: Grammarly does not understand language *at all*. The purpose of Grammarly is not to teach language to you. The purpose of Grammarly is to try and teach language to a piece of metal that literally does not even know what the word "language" means, or indeed that it has a meaning at all. Grammarly is not a tool written by humans for humans. It is a tool written for robots by morons. You are not in its target audience.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bug reports for a piece of software are best directed at developers of said piece of software.

Comment: You were right.

Comment: See [Are two singular nouns together singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/167374/26083) and [Agreement with compound subjects joined by “And”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/117346/26083).  See also [What’s the general consensus on “Grammarly”?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13678/26083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "is" and "are" are correct in your sentence.

If "doing research and inventing new things" is considered as representing a single idea, a singular verb is called for; If these are considered separate ideas, a plural verb is called for.

So it is not a question of right or wrong, strictly speaking.

But because in your case the two are closely related, I would prefer going with the "is" version myself.